# How to connect PC to router?

Tags: networking

My PC is normally connected to the internet via a modem. PC is upstairs, phone socket downstairs. All works well.

Now I've bought a router so that I can use a laptop in various rooms but I want to stay with the wired connection between the PC and router. There is no socket on the back of my PC so how do I connect? I've tried using one of the sockets on the back of the router through the modem but this does not work.

I've also searched the web but the solutions seem to be beyond my limited experience.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  Is this an old-fashioned dial up modem using a regular phone line (the kind that you have to manually connect and it makes all the screechy noises)?  You can't plug that into your router.  Those are going to be ethernet based.  You could attach it to the computer and share the connection that way, but since you say you don't have an ethernet port on the computer...(at least I think that's what you're trying to say)

EDIT: How is your computer connected to the modem right now?  Or do you have a cable running all the way from downstairs?

Comment: What kind of output does your modem have?

Comment: If you do have fax modem, it will be problematic to find a router for it. Only expensive routers support serial fax modems usually as a back-up option.